# Mysterious Minty Yams?

Tags: flavor

Last night some friends sliced and roasted some purple yams, which came out nicely. We were very perplexed, however, that 1 in 4 had a strong minty taste, a lot like teaberry. They didn't use any seasoning whatsoever, instead opting to have an array of sauces for dipping.

So why did the yams taste minty?

Comment: Is this per chance the Japanese variety, or Filipino "Ube" variety?

Comment: Quite possibly, I got them from H Mart, an Asian grocery chain. The skin was grey and the flesh (?) was a not-too-dark purple, if that helps.

Comment: @player3: Why don't you ask the people you bought it from? Maybe they would know.

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, but I'm guessing they got a cleaning/deodorizing product spilled on them. There's a reason it's illegal to store cleaning products on shelves above salable food, but there's also a lot of people who get dinged for it in health inspections. H-Mart is pretty clean, but I'm sure they aren't smelling all of the yams before they put em out.